# SSIS package Fails to execute

Tags: ssis, flat-file

`SSIS` package is scheduled to run at a particular time. If files before the scheduled time, the load goes fine, but when file arrived late, the package fails showing **error** message

```
Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Comment: What do you want it to do when the file arrives late?

Comment: We want the file to get fully copied and then the SSIS package to start processing it. Flat files could be upto 600MB.

Comment: The usual workaround is to first try copying the file somewhere. If that fails  you know the file is still in use. You need to build this and some retry functionality. You can also actually set up retries directly in the SQL Agent job - that's probably easiest

Answer (score 0):

Trap that specific error in the error handler, and if it occurs, have the job/package wait a while and try again until it no longer gets the error.

Comment: Can you explain how i can do that?

Comment: That's a broad topic with lots of ways it can be done.  It will require some research on your part.   As Nick mentioned in his comment, one way is to fail the package and set up retries in the Job.